# ElFinder With CodeIgniter | Unable to connect to backend

Tags: php, codeigniter, elfinder

I'm having problems using for the first time ElFinder with CodeIgniter. I've followed the installation wiki but i'm getting the following error "Unable to connect to backend". Can someone help me? I'm lost.

```
 Here the error:
 [enter image description here][1]

 Here is an example of the code that i think is the key:
```

> The elfinder url is: /home/optcenter/www/codeigniter/application/libraries

```
the upload forlder url:
```

> home/optcenter/www/codeigniter/uploads

This is my Elfinder_lib.php file

```
> <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access
> allowed');
>     
>     include_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'elfinder/elFinderConnector.class.php';
> include_once
> dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'elfinder/elFinder.class.php';
> include_once
> dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'elfinder/elFinderVolumeDriver.class.php';
> include_once
> dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'elfinder/elFinderVolumeLocalFileSystem.class.php';
>     
>     class Elfinder_lib  {   public function __construct($opts)    {
>         $connector = new elFinderConnector(new elFinder($opts));
>         $connector->run();   } }
```

Ex_controller.php

```
<?php function elfinder_init() {   $this->load->helper('path');   $opts = array(
    // 'debug' => true, 
    'roots' => array(
      array( 
        'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem', 
        'path'   => set_realpath('../uploads/'), 
        'URL'    => site_url('../uploads/') . '/'
        // more elFinder options here
      ) 
    )   );   $this->load->library('elfinder_lib', $opts); }
```

Part of my conector.php

```
 *  * @param  string  $attr  attribute name (read|write|locked|hidden)
* @param  string  $path  file path relative to volume root directory started with directory separator  * @return bool|null  **/ function access($attr, $path, $data, $volume) {     return strpos(basename($path), '.') === 0       // if file/folder begins with '.' (dot)         ? !($attr
== 'read' || $attr == 'write')    // set read+write to false, other (locked+hidden) set to true         :  null;                                 // else elFinder decide it itself }


// Documentation for connector options: // https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Connector-configuration-options $opts = array(    // 'debug' => true,     'roots' => array(       array(          'driver'        => 'LocalFileSystem',           // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)          'path'          => '../uploads/',  // path to files (REQUIRED)          'URL'           => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/../files/', // URL to files (REQUIRED)             'uploadDeny'    => array('all'),                // All Mimetypes not allowed to upload          'uploadAllow'   => array('image', 'text/plain'),// Mimetype `image` and `text/plain` allowed to upload          'uploadOrder'   => array('deny', 'allow'),      // allowed Mimetype `image` and `text/plain` only           'accessControl' => 'access'           // disable and hide dot starting files (OPTIONAL)         )   ) );

// run elFinder $connector = new elFinderConnector(new elFinder($opts)); $connector->run();
```

and the jQuery function that call the div container:

```
$(function() {
        var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
            // lang: 'ru',             // language (OPTIONAL)
            url : 'elfinder/connector.php'  // connector URL (REQUIRED)
        }).elfinder('instance');          
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you maybe need to modify some parts
if your Elfinder_lib.php is in application/libraries and all your Elfinder files to

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access
 allowed');

 include_once 'elfinder/elFinderConnector.class.php';
 include_once 'elfinder/elFinder.class.php';
 include_once 'elfinder/elFinderVolumeDriver.class.php';
 include_once 'elfinder/elFinderVolumeLocalFileSystem.class.php';

 class Elfinder_lib{
    public function __construct($opts){
         //for this part see the documentation
         $connector = new elFinderConnector(new elFinder($opts));
         $connector->run();   
    }
 }
```

in your controller.php

```
<?php 
 function elfinder_init(){
    $this->load->helper('path');   
    $opts = array(
                  //'debug' => true, 
                 'roots' => array(
                                  array( 
                                       'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem', 
                                       'path'   => set_realpath('./uploads/'), 
                                       'URL'    => site_url('./uploads/') . '/'
                                       //more elFinder options here
                                      ) 
                                  )
                 );

    $this->load->library('elfinder_lib', $opts);
 }
```

jQuery.jd

```
$(function() {
        var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
            // lang: 'ru',             // language (OPTIONAL)
            url : 'ex_controller/elfinder_init'  // connector URL (REQUIRED)
        }).elfinder('instance');          
    });
```

Comment: the same problem yet :'(

Comment: Unable to connect to backend.
Backend not found.

Comment: hey men, diving more deep in my code i could fix it :D, my problem was with path and URL in the conector, also i include the function elfinder_init on my sites_controller instead of creating the ex_controller :D

Comment: your recommendations help me a lot, and your answer is correct :D

Comment: I am grateful that it can help you to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to disable CSRF Protection in config.php file.
Edit config.php file in config folder :

```
$config['csrf_protection']  = TRUE;
```

To:

```
$config['csrf_protection']  = FALSE;
```